# Decoupling Client and Server - Common Patterns?

Tags: json, networking, mobile

Suppose you have a mobile app that needs to ask the server for 20 other `User`s near your current location.  The URL to get this data might look something like this (not escaped):

`https://example.com/api/users?lat=40.240239&long=-111.657920&count=20`

The server could then respond in one of two ways:

1. Return all `User` objects directly, as JSON, in one large array.
2. Return an array of `UUID`s corresponding to the `User`s who match the request. The client would then have two choices:

   a) Send a request for all `User` objects in one big batch:

   `https://example.com/api/users?ids=[1,2,3,4...]`

   b) Send requests for each `User` independently:

   `https://example.com/api/users?id=1`

   `https://example.com/api/users?id=2` ...

Currently, my application implements Option #1. In the name of responsiveness, I've eliminated every possible network round-trip by returning as much data as possible in as few requests as possible. However, I'm starting to see problems with this choice due to the fact that my client and server logic are very tightly coupled. It's difficult to maintain, versioning is a nightmare, and caching on the client side is much more difficult than say, Option #2b.

Based on your experience, which option do you recommend (or a different method entirely)?  What would you consider the "industry standard" way of serving data to a mobile app?

Comment: For your project, I would be gone with the Option 1. Why are maintenance and versioning a nightmare here?

Comment: What nightmare issues? 2b) would increase network traffic. 2a) could be applicable if you have larger data sets, but you state that its only 20 at a time. I really can't see how 1 is causing nightmares (especially as it is only 20 items) which 2 wouldn't. So you'll have to explain exactly what you think is so bad about it.

Comment: I've also seen scenarios where endpoints allow an `include` parameter so the client can request the full user object rather than just the id, but not do it  by default.

Comment: @SausageModulationMatrix The example I showed above is a simplification - in reality the application is quite a bit more complex. A `User` is also fairly large, relatively speaking, maybe somewhere around 1kb of JSON each. The biggest problem that I'm seeing is caching - Option 1 doesn't work well for libraries that map URL requests to data, since it has no concept of the independent `User` objects being returned. But if this is the way it's typically done, I'm willing to accept that.